# How to prove the following in Coq?

Tags: logic, coq

How to prove the following in Coq?

(p->q)->(~q->~p)

Here is what I started with:

```
Lemma work : (forall p q : Prop, (p->q)->(~q->~p)).
Proof.
  intros p q.
  intros p_implies_q not_q.
  intros p_true.
```

Comment: `unfold not in *.` unfolds the definition of negation (`~`). Can you take it from there?

Comment: So I do that after ````intros p_true````? Can you explain what do I do next?

Comment: If you're still stuck after that you need to go back and review your course material and find what parts of it you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
Lemma work : (forall p q : Prop, (p->q)->(~q->~p)).
Proof.
  intros p q.
  intros p_implies_q not_q.
  intros p_true.
  apply not_q.
  apply p_implies_q.
  auto.
Qed.
```

Some remarks:

- whenever you have a goal of the form `A -> B`,
  you can use `intros H` command to add `H: A` into your list of premises and be left with a goal `B`.
- `~P` is a syntactic sugar for `P -> False`. Thus, if your goal is `~P`, then `intros H` will add `H: P` to your premises list and reduce the goal to `False`
- If your goal is `Q` and you have a premise `H: P -> Q`, executing command `apply H` will change your goal to `P`
- Consecutive `intros` commands can be merged into one, so the proof can be shortened to

  ```
  Proof.
    intros p q p_implies_q not_q p_true.
    apply not_q.
    apply p_implies_q.
    auto.
  Qed.
  ```

Comment: Note: all occurrences of `false` should be replaced with `False` in your answer (indeed both terms exist in the standard library, albeit don't have the same type − `false : bool` vs. `False : Prop`)