# How to easily prove the following in Coq such as using only assumptions?

Tags: logic, coq

Is there an easy way to prove the following in Coq such as using only assumptions?

```
(P -> (Q /\ R)) -> (~Q) -> ~P
```

Comment: There have been many cases of questions on SO requesting help on homework exercises. While we can never tell for sure, the problem you are asking about is similar to those posts, which might be why you haven't found much help. I suggest you have a look at the Software Foundations textbook (https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/index.html), which is a great introduction to Coq.

Comment: Isn't this almost exactly what you asked two days ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54849221/how-to-prove-the-following-in-coq  The only difference is that here you need to destruct (with `match`) the result from applying the first argument to something.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague... Do you wonder if it is possible (yes), what the answer is (see Arthur's comment above), or how to think about solving these problems?

In the latter case, remember that the goal is to create a "lambda-term" with the specified type.  You can either use "tactics" which are helping you construct the term "from the outside and inwards.  It is good to do it by hand a couple of times to understand what is going on and what the tactics really do, which I think is why you are given this exercise.

If you look at your example,

```
(P -> (Q /\ R)) -> (~Q) -> ~P
```

you can see that it is a function of three (!) arguments.  It is because the last type `~P` really means `P -> False`, so the *types* of the arguments to the function that you need to create are

```
P -> (Q /\ R)
Q -> False
P
```

and the function should construct a term of type

```
False
```

You can create a term `fun A B C => _` where `A, B, C` has the types above, (this is what the tactic `intros` does), and you need to come up with a term that should go into the hole `_` by combining the terms `A, B, C` and the raw gallina constructions.

In this case, when you have managed to create a term of type `Q /\ R` you will have to "destruct" it to get the term of type `Q`,  (Hint: for that you will have to use the `match` construction).

Hope this helps without spoiling the fun!